# Does linking to Discord from a game app breach COPPA restrictions?

Tags: minor, coppa

I'm developing a mobile game and we want to link our Discord in the menu. The game is going to release both on iOS and Android.

Am I allowed to link Discord in it or would that interfere with the COPPA laws? I read that the COPPA restricts communication with minors inside and outside of the app.

Comment: Are you marketing this to kids under 13?

Answer (score 1):

So, Discord, in its workings, is NOT COPPA compliant. If you just hop on any old Discord server, you'll see.

So linking to it *might* interfere with COPPA laws.

To be safe, you can put in a popup/prompt that verifies that the user is above 13 (or whatever that age limit is). If the user lies, you get plausible deniability, and if the user tells the truth, well, then it's COPPA friendly.

"I'm not a lawyer, this isn't legal advice"